# Problem while using Group_by/mutate function in R

Tags: r, group-by, rstudio, dplyr

I am trying to calculate the variance between preceding rows using group_by and lag on the below dataframe

```
ID    DATE      Value
555  1/9/2018    10
555  2/9/2018    20
555  3/9/2018    50
555  4/9/2018    70
000  1/9/2018    0
000  2/9/2018    5
000  3/9/2018    15
111  1/9/2018    0
111  2/9/2018    15
111  3/9/2018    20
111  4/9/2018    25
```

The difference is supposed to show as follow:

```
ID    DATE      Value    Diff
555  1/9/2018    10       0
555  2/9/2018    20       10
555  3/9/2018    50       30
555  4/9/2018    70       20
000  1/9/2018    0        0
000  2/9/2018    5        5
000  3/9/2018    15       10
111  1/9/2018    0        0
111  2/9/2018    15       15
111  3/9/2018    20       5
111  4/9/2018    25       5
```

By using this line of code

```
data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(DATE) %>%
  mutate(Diff= Value - lag(Value, default = first(Value)))
```

It skips the grouping condition by ID and calculate the difference between all the rows like this:

```
ID    DATE      Value    Diff
555  1/9/2018    10       0
555  2/9/2018    20       10
555  3/9/2018    50       30
555  4/9/2018    70       20
000  1/9/2018    0        -70
000  2/9/2018    5        5
000  3/9/2018    15       10
111  1/9/2018    0        -15
111  2/9/2018    15       15
111  3/9/2018    20       5
111  4/9/2018    25       5
```

Comment: To me your code works fine, just the order or rows is different.

Comment: Actually, your code works fine for me as well.

Comment: @JuliusVainora can concatenation affects the group_by? because the ID is originally concatenated from 2 columns

Comment: @ZidaneAhmed, if I understand correctly what you mean, concatenation alone shouldn't be a problem, but perhaps the way it was done (the order of different actions, e.g.) has an effect. I guess you should revise your example.

Comment: Your code works fine. Diff = c(0, diff(Value)) is another option where you dont need to use lag...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me (with a little tweak).

```
> data_new
# A tibble: 11 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
   ID    DATE     Value  Diff
   <chr> <fct>    <int> <int>
 1 555   1/9/2018    10     0
 2 555   2/9/2018    20    10
 3 555   3/9/2018    50    30
 4 555   4/9/2018    70    20
 5 000   1/9/2018     0     0
 6 000   2/9/2018     5     5
 7 000   3/9/2018    15    10
 8 111   1/9/2018     0     0
 9 111   2/9/2018    15    15
10 111   3/9/2018    20     5
11 111   4/9/2018    25     5
```

#### Code

```
data_new <- data %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Diff = Value - lag(Value, default = first(Value)))
```

#### Data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c("555", "555", "555", "555", "000", "000", 
"000", "111", "111", "111", "111"), DATE = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1/9/2018", "2/9/2018", 
"3/9/2018", "4/9/2018"), class = "factor"), Value = c(10L, 20L, 
50L, 70L, 0L, 5L, 15L, 0L, 15L, 20L, 25L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```